# Scrapy start_urls

Tags: python, scrapy

[The script](https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot/blob/master/dirbot/spiders/dmoz.py) (below) from [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) tutorial contains two `start_urls`.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from dirbot.items import Website

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        The lines below is a spider contract. For more info see:
        http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html
        @url http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/
        @scrapes name
        """
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('text()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

But why does it scrape only these 2 web pages? I see  `allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]` but these two pages also contain links to other pages which are within `dmoz.org` domain! Why doesnt it scrape them too?

Answer (score 17):

`start_urls` class attribute contains start urls - nothing more. If you have extracted urls of other pages you want to scrape - yield from `parse` callback corresponding requests with [another] callback:

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'my_spider'
    start_urls = [
                'http://www.domain.com/'
    ]
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        '''Parse main page and extract categories links.'''
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        urls = hxs.select("//*[@id='tSubmenuContent']/a[position()>1]/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)
            self.log('Found category url: %s' % url)
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parseCategory)

    def parseCategory(self, response):
        '''Parse category page and extract links of the items.'''
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select("//*[@id='_list']//td[@class='tListDesc']/a/@href").extract()
        for link in links:
            itemLink = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link)
            self.log('Found item link: %s' % itemLink, log.DEBUG)
            yield Request(itemLink, callback = self.parseItem)

    def parseItem(self, response):
        ...
```

If you still want to customize start requests creation, override method [BaseSpider.start_requests()](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests)

Answer (score 6):

start_urls contain those links from which the spider start crawling.
If you want crawl recursively you should use crawlspider and define rules for that.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html
look there for example.

Answer (score 2):

The class does not have a `rules` property. Have a look at http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/intro/overview.html and search for "rules" to find an example.

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html  but rules are for CrawlSpiders! i inherit from BaseSpider!

Comment: The BaseSpider only goes to the start URLs provided, so I guess my original answer is a little misleading. See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider

Comment: but it tells about start_urls:  The subsequent URLs will be generated successively from data contained in the start URLs. Why doesnt it scrape those (subsequent) urls?? (of course, if those urls are within dmoz.org domain)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `BaseSpider`, inside the callback, you have to extract out your desired urls yourself and return a `Request` object.

If you use `CrawlSpider`, links  extraction would be taken care of by the rules and the SgmlLinkExtractor associated with the rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an rule to follow links (that is already implemented in scrapy), the spider will scrape them too. I hope have helped...

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import BaseSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


    class Spider(BaseSpider):
        name = 'my_spider'
        start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/']
        allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
        rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[], deny[]), follow=True)]

     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't write the function to deal the urls what you want to get.so two way to reslolve.1.use the the rule (crawlspider) 2:write the function to deal the new urls.and put them in the callback function.