# Dynamic spider generation with Scrapy subclass init error

Tags: python, web-crawler, bots, scrapy

I am trying to write a generic "Master" spider that I use with "start_urls" and "allowed_domains" inserted dynamically during execution. (Eventually, I will have these in a database, that I will pull and then use to initialize and crawl a new spider for each DB entry.)

At the moment, I have two files:

1. MySpider.py -- Establishes my "master" spider class.
2. RunSpider.py -- proof of concept for executing the initialization of my dynamically generated spiders.

For writing these two files, I referenced the following:

- [Passing Arguments into spiders at Scrapy.org](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments)
- [Running Scrapy from a script at Scrapy.org](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)
- [General Spider structure within Pyton at Scrapy.org](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders)
- These two questions here on StackOverflow were the best help I could find: [Creating a generic scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814827/creating-a-generic-scrapy-spider); [Scrapy start_urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903730/scrapy-start-urls)

I considered [scrapyD](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#how-scrapyd-works), but I don't think its what I'm looking for...

Here is what I have written:

MySpider.py --

```
import scrapy

class BlackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Black1'

    def __init__(self, allowed_domains=[], start_urls=[], *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlackSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = start_urls
        self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains
        #For Testing: 
        print start_urls
        print self.start_urls
        print allowed_domains
        print self.allowed_domains

    def parse(self, response):
        #############################
        # Insert my parse code here #
        #############################
        return items
```

RunSpider.py --

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from MySpider import BlackSpider

#Set my allowed domain (this will come from DB later)
ad = ["example.com"]
#Set my start url
sd = ["http://example.com/files/subfile/dir1"]

#Initialize MySpider with the above allowed domain and start url
MySpider = BlackSpider(ad,sd)

#Crawl MySpider
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

**PROBLEM:**

Here is my problem -- When I execute this, it appears to successfully pass in my arguments for allowed_domains and start_urls; HOWEVER, after MySpider is initialized, when I run the spider to crawl, the specified urls / domains are no longer found and no website is crawled. I added the print statement above to show this:

```
me@mybox:~/$ python RunSpider.py 
['http://example.com/files/subfile/dir1']
['http://example.com/files/subfile/dir1']
['example.com']
['example.com']
2016-02-26 16:11:41 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
2016-02-26 16:11:41 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
...
[]
[]
[]
[]
2016-02-26 16:11:41 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
...
2016-02-26 16:11:41 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
...
2016-02-26 16:11:41 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
...
2016-02-26 16:11:41 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Why is my spider initialized correctly, but when I try to execute the spider the urls are missing?  Is this a basic Python programming (class?) error that I am just missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation on `CrawlerProcess`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess)

- `CrawlerProcess.crawl()` expects either a `crawler` or a `scrapy.Spider` subclass, not an instance of a `Spider`
- spider arguments are to be passed as additional arguments to `.crawl()`

So you need to do something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from myspider import BlackSpider

#Set my allowed domain (this will come from DB later)
ad = ["example.com"]
#Set my start url
sd = ["http://example.com/files/subfile/dir1"]

#Crawl MySpider
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})
# pass Spider class, and other params as keyword arguments
process.crawl(MySpider, allowed_domains=ad, start_urls=sd)
process.start()
```

You can see this in action with scrapy commands themselves, [for example `scrapy runspider`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.0.5/scrapy/commands/runspider.py#L73):

```
def run(self, args, opts):
    ...
    spidercls = spclasses.pop()

    self.crawler_process.crawl(spidercls, **opts.spargs)
    self.crawler_process.start()
```

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly. Thank you so much for the references and your detailed answer, Paul!